# How to update Git (actually remove apple git and install new one via brew)?

Tags: macos, install, bash, homebrew, git

I want to update git. I find this article:

On one of the first steps, I get a problem. When I tried to backup currently installed git I got permissions restriction. It's ok it must be some OSX system restriction.

I checked PATH and noticed that `/usr/bin` is after `/usr/local/bin`. So if I just install new version of git via brew this version will be used (since brew installs everything into `/usr/local/bin`. I did that and the result frustrated me. Old git is using instead of installed via brew. Why?

Here is some output:

```
svlad at sharikovvlad in ~/sandbox/git-test on master [+]
$ git --version
git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)

svlad at sharikovvlad in ~/sandbox/git-test on master [+]
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

svlad at sharikovvlad in ~/sandbox/git-test on master [+]
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/git | grep git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 svlad  admin  28 Sep  3 18:16 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.14.1/bin/git

svlad at sharikovvlad in ~/sandbox/git-test on master [+]
$ /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.14.1/bin/git --version
git version 2.14.1

svlad at sharikovvlad in ~/sandbox/git-test on master [+]
$ echo $PATH
/Users/svlad/bin:/usr/local/opt/gnupg@1.4/libexec/gpgbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
$
```

So why apple git is using? `/usr/local/bin` is first in path so symlink from this folder must be used? So why I am getting old version?

Also, any thoughts how can I remove apple git?

Comment: "On one of the first steps, I get a problem. When I tried to backup currently installed git I got permissions restriction. It's ok it must be some OSX system restriction." Yep—it's called System Integrity Protection and it prevents you from modifying certain system files, including anything in /usr/bin. You _could_ just disable SIP and delete or replace /usr/bin/git—although that's really not a good solution.

Comment: Have you tried a new terminal or rebooted sinc installing the homebrew git?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Hi! Thank you for your response! Yep it is not good solution at all.

Comment: @Mark Yes I restarted mac many times after installing homebrew.

Comment: Actually why I can not remove is not the question. The main question is why   OS choose git from `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`? `local` dir is on the left and as I know macos try to find command in each dir in PATH and it is going from left to right. So git in `/usr/local/bin` should be resolved firstly. Why git from `/usr/bin` is used then?

Comment: What does /usr/local/bin/git —version give and why do you pass the ls through grep?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove CLI tools alone, which is what comes with Apple git and that may solve your problem.

**CLI Tools Removal**

- https://gist.github.com/yoneken/3284561

if that didn't do it, that means that CLI Tools were downloaded separate from Xcode and you can try this to remove it:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Once that's gone you just check to make sure it got removed and then reinstall it with Homebrew. Hope this may help.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is a good idea to remove something installed out of the box. Main question is why git from `usr/bin` is used, not from `/usr/local/bin`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297286/how-to-update-git-actually-remove-apple-git-and-install-new-one-via-brew?noredirect=1#comment375803_297286